# Accessing local IIS website in a workgroup from another PC using the host name

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, virtualhost, hosts-file

I've a local website in my IIS 7.5 and the hostname I specified as samplesite.com and have added the bindings as * and the IP of my PC 192.168.1.2.
Also added the host entry in hosts file

Everything working fine in my local machine when I enter samplesite.com in browser. But my problem is I cant access the site from a PC in my same workgroup. How can I make it possible or what are the steps I've to do in both pc to make it work.
[image: IIS Binding]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse a website on another pc's IIS, you need to type 192.168.1.2/websitename from the remote pc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check that the firewall, which is set up on the machine with the site, does not block 80th port.

Then you have two options:

you either remove host name from the bindings and use the machine ip (http://192.168.1.2) as the site url everywhere in your local network

or you have to add host enry `192.168.1.2 samplesite.com` to hosts file on every machine where you whant to get access to the site. In this case you can continue to use http://samplesite.com url.